# Django ORM временные юзеры

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-orm

Добрый день подскажите как создать таблицу для временных пользователей , допустим что бы через неделю она сама очищалась?

Каждый пользователь который задёт записывается в бд что бы получить корзину.

```
class CartMixin(View):
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            if not customer:
                customer= Customer.objects.create(
                    user=request.user
                )
            cart = Cart.objects.filter(owner=customer,in_order=False).first()
            if not cart:
                cart= Cart.objects.create(owner=customer)
        else:
            session_key=request.session.session_key
            name=str(session_key)
            user= User.objects.filter(username=name).first()
            if not user:
                user = User.objects.create_user(name, 'randomemail', 'randomemail')
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=user).first()
            if not customer:

                customer= Customer.objects.create(
                    user=user 
                )
          
            cart= Cart.objects.filter(for_anonymoys_user=True,owner=customer,in_order=False).first()
            if not cart:
                cart= Cart.objects.create(for_anonymoys_user=True,owner=customer)
        self.cart=cart
        self.cart.save()
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: А точнее, в чём смысл задачи? Будут ли постоянные пользователи? Кто будет создавать временных? Ведь технически это реализовать можно множеством разных способов, например определить профайл пользователя, в котором доопределять статус живучести пользователя, или создавать в БД сущность она отключение юзера, и регулярным заданием обрабатывать эти записи.

Comment: Смысл в том , что когда заходит пользователь на сайт для него создается корзина,  код дополню в вопросе

Comment: Для корзины создавать пользователя совершенно не обязательно, достаточно привязать корзину к сессии посетителя (а старые сессии чистятся managment-командой clearsessions). Если есть смелость, можно даже хранить корзину прямо в браузерных куках, не храня на стороне сервера вообще ничего.